# how to append data in one dataframe from different files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have used the following code to read the data from the files. I tried to make a time series data in one data frame but I am missing somewhere.

```
files = glob.glob('*.txt')
files.sort()
for infile in files:
    year,formatt = infile.split('.')
    year = year.split('_')[1]
    ws = [4,9,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
    df = pd.read_fwf(infile,widths=ws,header=9, nrows=31, keep_default_na = False)
    df = df.drop('Day', 1)
    df = np.array(df.T)
    df = df[df != '']
    data = pd.DataFrame([])
    data['Discharge'] = df
    data = data.set_index(pd.date_range(year, periods=len(data), freq='D'),
                            drop=True, append=False, inplace=False, verify_integrity=False)
    new = pd.DataFrame([])
    all_ = new.append(data)
    print all_
```

can anyone help me to figure out my problem?

my sample data is in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rkXkOkG7ExSWQ5djloNkpNWmc

Comment: What is missing exactly?

Comment: I want all the data in one dataframe in time series format.

Comment: I suggest you define an empty list outside of your loop, append to that list of each df in your look and then call `pd.concat` on the list